# uasort sorting all array, but i need by one attribute

Tags: php, sorting

this is problem bellow

```
$array[] = [
    'priority' => 0,
    'name' => 'a'
];
$array[] = [
    'priority' => 0,
    'name' => 'b'
];
$array[] = [
    'priority' => 10,
    'name' => 'c'
];
$array[] = [
    'priority' => 0,
    'name' => 'b'
];

function sortByPriority($a, $b){
    if ($a['priority'] == $b['priority']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['priority'] < $b['priority']) ? -1 : 1;
}
var_dump($array);
uasort($array, 'sortByPriority');
var_dump($array);
```

i expected that only 3rd element will be last, but element with name = 'a' now in 3rd position. why? it must be on 1st place!

UPD:
i expected ordering (a,b,b,c) but i see on screen b,b,a,c

Comment: Cause you only order by priority and not by name, so this is randomly ordered between offset 0, 1, 3 and 2 is always the last one.

Comment: ty for answer. I dont want sort array by name - only by priority. It is imposible?

Comment: alas, usort is not 'stable' for equal entries: [php.net/manual/en/function.usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#38827)

Comment: But it is sorted by priority. You wanted `(0,0,0,10)` and got it. If that's not what you wanted then you need to adjust your function to consider name as well.

Comment: i want to change element position only if it need it. in my example element with name = 'a' not need to change position

Comment: This is not how it works, it sorts depending of an algorithm...
With a sort algorithm, whatever the initial order, the final order should be always the same.
You could order by priority and if equals, order by name

Answer (score 1):

ryan-vincent give me a solution link, thank you

[SOLUTION](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#38827)

UPDATE

better solution use a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

```
//decorate
array_walk( $array,create_function('&$v, $k', '$v = [$v[\'priority\'], $k, $v];'));
//sort
sort($array);
//undecorate
array_walk( $array, create_function('&$v, $k', '$v = $v[2];'));
```